# Is there a working VS Code plugin to get CSS suggestions for styled components?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, styled-components

I already tried the popular plugins available. But none of them is working. What I saw is that the most popular one was supposed to work with emmet but it has some bug and it's no longer working. And all the questions related to this I can find is older and probably from the times when these extensions was working. Apparently my company uses styled components and it seems like the worst choice possible cuz of no intellisense plugins that work. It's too slow to type any css. If anyone could suggest me any kind of work around for this or plugins that work  I'd be grateful.

Comment: which one have you used?

Comment: I used the previous popular ones.. it wasn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the extension! Apparently they moved the original extension.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=styled-components.vscode-styled-components